# Retrieving multiple firebase nodes swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im retrieving data from a firebase backend which is below. My JSON structure has 2 child notes from my understanding  With the code in my view did load, i can access the users node and i can print the "email" & "provider" -

However, my main goal is to actually access the 'planits' node and get the "images" & "planit" details. I am just pretty stuck on a way to implement that. I would appreciate any and all of the help provided. Thank you!

[image]

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    refHandle = ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        print(dataDict)

    })


    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
         //Get user value
         if snapshot.exists() == true {

            for child in snapshot.children {

                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let EmailString = value!["email"] as! String

                self.userEmail.append(EmailString)
                print(self.userEmail)

// BELOW IS MY FAILED ATTEMPT AT ACCESSING THE 'planits' node - Nothing Prints

                let image = value!["images"] as! String
                print(image)


        }
    }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: You're loading the `users` and then trying to get the `images`, but `images` are in the `planits` section. You'll need a separate load to `ref.child("planits") to get those images. You may need to do some kind of filter like `where("senderId", isEqualTo: userID)` or something, I'm not sure I'm using Firestore atm but you should have some equivalent. Maybe...

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Yes I’m currently studying and reading on this now. You’re correct in your approach and method according to what I’m reading now. Quick question- would they filter be so that I’m sure I get posts that are associated with the user who posted?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. I'm not 100% sure that you have those filter methods with Firebase, like I said I'm using Firestore and the filter methods are very useful.

Comment: Simply create another firebase call and change this *ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent* to this *ref.child("planits").child(some_planit_id!).observeSingleEvent*. That will retrieve a single planit with some_planit_id - just like your users call getting a single user. Your followup comment/question about 'filtering' is unclear as if you know *some_planit_id* you don't need to filter (query) as you can access that node directly since you know it's specific id